# Javascript doesn't always run before form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a form, and before the form being sent, I have a Javascript which changes some fields before sending the form.

It always work for me and for most of my users, but I've noticed in Google Analytics that sometimes the fields are not changed for some users.

They must have JS activated otherwise they wouldn't show up in Analytics. And it is not due to an old version of IE (<8) because I can see their browser and OS are all differences.

I haven't a clue as to why it wouldn't work for some, do you have an idea by looking at the code?

```js
document.forms['myform'].addEventListener('submit', function() {
  // send analytics event
  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Submit form',
    eventAction: 'click',
    transport: 'beacon'
  });

  var myredirect = 'http://' + document.querySelector('#myform #myformp').value + '.DestinationWebSite.com/?SOURCE=' + document.querySelector('#myform #myformsource').value + '&FNAME=' + document.querySelector('#myform #myformfname').value + '&LNAME=' + document.querySelector('#myform #myformlname').value + '&EMAIL=' + document.querySelector('#myform #myformemail').value + '&PHONE=' + document.querySelector('#myform #myformphone').value;

  document.querySelector('#myform #myformredirect').value = myredirect;
  document.querySelector('#myform #myformredirectonlist').value = myredirect;
  document.querySelector('#myform #myformname').value = document.querySelector('#myform #myformfname').value + ' ' + document.querySelector('#myform #myformlname').value;

  setCookie('fname', document.querySelector('#myform #myformfname').value, 7);
  setCookie('lname', document.querySelector('#myform #myformlname').value, 7);
  setCookie('email', document.querySelector('#myform #myformemail').value, 7);
  setCookie('phone', document.querySelector('#myform #myformphone').value, 7);
  setCookie('source', document.querySelector('#myform #myformsource').value, 7);
  setCookie('p', document.querySelector('#myform #myformp').value, 7);

});
```

Thank you

---

EDIT : it could be users using Adblock or similar who have this problem with the script. I don't know why because it hasn't any pattern included in adblock's filter lists. But one user on another forum where I asked this question went to my site and made a test with and without adblock and he was able to reproduce the bug.
I don't use adblock myself so I would never have been able to find the culprit.

Comment: Why would you use `document.querySelector('#myform #myformredirect')` and such rather than `document.getElementById('myformredirect')`?

Comment: Are you saying that it is just Google Analytics that gets the unupdated values, or that even the actual form submit sends the unupdated values? (Also, would it kill you to indent your code?)

Comment: I used querySelector because I've read it was the "new" way of handling everything instead of getElementById and the rest. Could it come from that? I've looked at browser support for querySelector and it seems well supported except by IE < 8. I'm not saying Google Analytics gets the unupdated values, I was mentionning Google Analytics just to say that the users must have JS enabled, it's the form field which don't get updated. I haven't checked if the GA event is being sent for those users. (Sorry about indenting)